# Is it possible to use django to load a file from a system directory?

Tags: python, django, image, http, webserver

Basically, let's say I have an image in `/home/arnav/Documents/covers`. My django project directory is `/home/arnav/project`. Is it possible for django to somehow access image files in `covers` and use them as part of a template? Or do images need to be stored within the project to be accessed? Thanks.

Comment: You can make your web server and filesystem do anything you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your settings file define `STATICFILES_DIRS` to also include the `/home/arnav/Documents/covers` path:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     '/home/arnav/project/static',
     '/home/arnav/Documents/covers',
)
```

This will tell django to first look in the project static directory, but also look in covers for static files.